# Segmentation fault when generating input from another source

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

For a homework assignment i must perform a buffer overflow attack on a program of theirs. The code of that program is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void vulnerable_function(char *input)
{
   char buffer[256];
   strcopy(buffer, input);
   printf("buffer:%s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   vulnerable_function(argv[1]);
}
```

So, when i execute this command on the terminal: perl -e 'print "A"x32' | ./opdr1_vuln i always get a segmentation fault, no matter how large we generate our input.

The program terminated with:

```
#0  0xb7f17f50 in strcopy () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
```

However, when i manually fill in many a's in the terminal as this:

```
./opdr1_vuln aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

it crashes at 260's a's, which is expected and when i debug this with gdb it gives another segmentation fault. It looks like if I'm generating input from another source than the terminal itself, it gives a segmentation fault with strcopy().

I compiled the program with:

```
# gcc opdr1_vuln.c -o opdr1_vuln
```

It's a Linux debian 2.6.18-4-686 i686 system.

I don't know why this happens, can someone help me?

Comment: `vulnerable_function(argv[1]);` you're not checking the argument count, and you're not passing any arguments... to be able to properly attack, you have to provide an argument, not a standard input.

Comment: Where do you have the `strcopy` function .

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre isn't `argv[]` `NULL`-terminated? As `argv[0]` is the own program name, `argv[1]` should be `NULL:`

Comment: yes, I have fixed that. It's still undefined behaviour to read from NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

```
perl -e 'print "A"x32' | ./opdr1_vuln
```

you're not passing any parameters, you're just providing standard input to your program

`argv[1]` is then invalid (`NULL`) and since argument count is not checked you get undefined behaviour (the function is vulnerable, but the `main` program is as well)

To provide the output of the perl command to your code you have to pass the output *as an argument*, not as input. In a classic `bash` that would be:

```
./opdr1_vuln `perl -e 'print "A"x32'`
```

or (maybe more readable)

```
./opdr1_vuln $(perl -e 'print "A"x32')
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I piped it because if i pass that command to the program as an argument is just prints buffer: perl -e print. So i don't know why this litte perl script does not get executed then.

Comment: note the backquotes (let me provide another syntax)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! It works now. I did confuse normal quotes with backticks.

Comment: that's why the "modern" bash syntax uses `$()` for the best. It's recommended to use it. BTW tell your teacher that running the program _without_ any argument is _already_ an attack. Good job :): (Ronin: "I could ambush you with a cup of coffee")

Comment: That modern syntax is a lot more clear indeed. But you mean that it's already an attack, because you let the program crash without a parameter as it throws a segmentation fault? :) I wonder what you can do with this though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157659/discussion-between-maikkeyy-and-jean-francois-fabre).